# Get strings after second space—if any—and then put them into a variable

Tags: php, regex, string, variables, space

I am dealing with dynamic user input, that can contain more than one space. What I am actually want to process is user's name. For examples: `John` `John Doe`, `John Doe Michael`, `John Doe Michael Moore`.

I have 2 variables. The first variable is for first name, so I just name it `$fname` and the second variable is for last name, let's name it `$lname`.

I want to put any string without space or any part of string before the first space to variable for first name or `$fname` and any part after the first space to the last name variable or `$lname` without removing the space between them.

So, if a user give names like `John Doe Michael Moore`, then I want to put `John` into the variable `$fname` and `Doe Michael Moore` into the variable `$lname`.

Here is my current approach:

```
$name = ( $_POST['name'] );

if(strpos($name, " ")) {
$name = explode(' ', $name);
$count = count($name);

    $fname = '';
    $lname = '';

    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        if($i == 0) {
            $fname .= $name[$i];
        } elseif($i == 1) {
            $lname .= $name[$i];
        } else {
            $lname .= ' ' . $name[$i];
        }
    }   
}
```

But I don't like to use loop in this situation. Is there any solution like using regex or something else?

Comment: Sure, `'/^(\w+)\s*(.*)/'` should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for regular expressions; if you're pretty certain you will receive at least two names, you can keep the `explode()` as you have it:

```
list($fname, $lname) = explode(' ', $name, 2);
```

The third argument to `explode()` will limit the result to at most two elements. The `list()` performs the assignment to your two variables.

Answer (score 1):

get it from the 2 matched groups.

```
^(\w+)\s+(.*)$
```

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/zN2vG6/18)

Sample code:

```
$re = "/^(\\w+)\\s+(.*)$/";
$str = "John Doe Michael Moore";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

output:

```
1.  [0-4]   `John`
2.  [5-22]  `Doe Michael Moore`
```

Answer (score 1):

Then just use [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) but limit the array to two items like this:

```
// Set test data array.
$test_name_array = array('John', 'John Doe', 'John Doe Michael', 'John Doe Michael Moore');    

// Roll through the test data array.
foreach ($test_name_array as $name) {

  // Break the array into two parts.
  $name = explode(' ', $name, 2);
  $fname = isset($name[0]) && !empty($name[0]) ? $name[0] : '';
  $lname = isset($name[1]) && !empty($name[1]) ? $name[1] : '';

  // Check the output of `$name` for debugging.
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($name);
  echo '</pre>';

  // Echo the first name.
  echo 'First Name: ' . $fname;
  echo '<br />';

  // Echo the last name.
  echo 'Last Name: ' . $lname;
  echo '<br />';

}
```

And the output of that would be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => John
)

First Name: John
Last Name: 

Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => John Doe
)

First Name: 
Last Name: John Doe

Array
(
    [0] => John
    [1] => Doe Michael
)

First Name: John
Last Name: Doe Michael

Array
(
    [0] => John
    [1] => Doe Michael Moore
)

First Name: John
Last Name: Doe Michael Moore
```

Answer (score 0):

RegEx for first name:

```
^.*(?=[^ ]*)$
```

RegEx for last name:

```
[^ ]*$
```

Use this if you're certain that no last name in this world would ever include a whitespace character, which is not true. What is stopping you from giving the user the chance to tell you what's their actual first and what's their last name? I think this lack of UI/API functionality is the actual problem here.